# Aptana Studio is opening but not ever closing a python.exe process

Tags: python, django, aptana

I am developing a small testing website using Django 1.2 in Aptana Studio build  2.0.4.1268158907. I have a Django project that I test by running the command "runserver 8001" on my project. This command runs the project on a small server that comes with Django.

However the problem arises that every time I run this command Aptana opens two instances of the process "python.exe". Upon terminating the command only one of these instances is ended. The other process continues to run and use memory. My server is not online, and the process doesn't seem to do anything that I can find. This happens every time i run the runserver command on my project and therefore more and more python.exe instances will open up through my development period.

Any help discovering either the purpose of this extra python.exe or a way to prevent it from opening would be much appreciated.

Comment: Assuming you are running on Windows, have you looked at the child processes in Process Explorer?

Comment: Simple workaround: python manage.py runserver from command line

Comment: Perhaps this should be moved to superuser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try adding --noreload to the runserver argument